# Actual job ID of a slurm array job

Tags: slurm

I sometimes run job arrays in our slurm cluster:

```
#SBATCH --output=/vol/cluster-data/gprezza/logs/%x_%j.out
#SBATCH --error=/vol/cluster-data/gprezza/logs/%x_%j.err
#SBATCH --array=1-21%5
```

Once they run, on squeue I see:

```
1145141_[12-21%5]       cpu    align  gprezza PD       0:00
    1145141_11       cpu    align  gprezza  R       1:42 
     1145141_2       cpu    align  gprezza  R    3:58:52     
     1145141_1       cpu    align  gprezza  R    4:00:36   
     1145141_9       cpu    align  gprezza  R    1:17:44  
     1145141_7       cpu    align  gprezza  R    3:14:59
```

How do I get the actual job id of each job? I need it to check the output and error files. For example job 1145141_1 has as id 1145144 (the output file is at /vol/cluster-data/gprezza/logs/align_1145144.out).

Comment: You can check them with `scontrol`. And you can also change the output and error file names for others easier for you.

Comment: @Poshi do you mind expanding on both points?

Comment: You can expand yourself with `man scontrol` for the first point (look for the `show` command) and for the second point, just use a different name in the `--error` and `--output` parameters of `sbatch`, probably including the job array IDs (more details in `man sbatch`).

Answer (score 0):

The `squeue` command accepts a `--format` parameter for choosing the information that is shown for each job. By default, it is

```
"%.18i %.9P %.8j %.8u %.2t %.10M %.6D %R"
```

where the first part `%.18i` is the job ID.

You can replace that first part with `%.18A` to get the actual job  ID

So

```
squeue --format "%.18A %.9P %.8j %.8u %.2t %.10M %.6D %R"
```

should show what you are looking for.

Note that you can specify the format with env variable `SQUEUE_FORMAT` to avoid adding it explicitly each time, or define an alias.